# puts statement is printing on two lines

Tags: ruby, class, puts

I have a class called `PolynomialElements` and inside that class I have a method called `printElement` that has a puts statement that print two variables.  The puts statement is printing the variables on different lines.  How do I get puts to print the two variables on one line.  My code is below, it is line #5 where the puts statement is.

```
class PolynomialElements
  attr_accessor :element, :size

  def printElement
       puts "#{element}x^#{size}"
  end
end


askAgain = true
polyArray = Array.new

while askAgain
  puts "How many numbers do you want to enter? "
  numString = gets
  num = numString.to_i
  while num > 0
    puts "Enter a value for the Polynomial "
    value = gets
    polyArray.push(value)
    num -= 1
  end

  sizeOfArray = polyArray.length
  polyArray.each do |x|
    var = PolynomialElements.new
    var.element = x
    sizeOfArray -= 1
    var.size = sizeOfArray
    var.printElement
  end
  puts "Enter y to enter new number or anything else to quit"
  cont = gets
  if cont.chomp != "y"
    askAgain = false
  else
    polyArray.clear
  end
end
```

Comment: As you may know, the Ruby convention is to use *snake-case* for the names of methods and variables; e.g., `size_of_array` rather than `sizeOfArray`. Conventions are perhaps made to be broken, but I'd say that 99%+ of Rubiests follow that (and other) conventions. Among other things, departing from convention--in any language--may leave the impression with  readers that you are inexperienced with the language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `while` loop change:

```
value = gets
```

to:

```
value = gets.chomp
```

You will then get:

```
Enter a value for the Polynomial 
3
1x^2
2x^1
3x^0
```